# Mongoose - getting a single document per value for a given field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

For a collection with 200k documents like the following:

```
{ 
  name: Mario,
  profession: plumber,
  level: 8,
},
{
  name: Luigi,
  profession: plumber,
  level: 5,
},
{
  name: Walter,
  profession: cook,
  level: 10,
},
{
  name: Jesse,
  profession: cook,
  level: 3,
}
```

What would be an efficient query to get only a single document per profession, with or without sorting by level?

Comment: use the aggregation framework with a **`$group`** stage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on @felix answer, you can do this easily with a [MongoDB group operation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/). For example, in the MongoDB shell:

```
db.yourCollection.aggregate([
  { $group: { _id: '$profession', doc: { $first: '$$ROOT' } } }
])
```

will give you results like:

```
{
  _id: 'plumber',
  doc: {
    name: 'Mario',
    profession: 'plumber',
    level: 8
  }
},
{
  _id: 'cook',
  doc: {
    ...
  }
},
...
```

If more fine-grained control is required, you can filter the results before or after the grouping with [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/).  Any MongoDB adaptor for Node should give you access to this method.

Answer (score 0):

use the **$group** and **aggregate()** function to get your expected result

**Query:**

```
 db.getCollection('agg').aggregate([
      { $group: { _id: '$profession', doc: { $first: '$$ROOT' }, count: { $sum: 1 } } }
    ])
```

**Output:**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "cook",
    "doc" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("59157ace263af55a862b78dc"),
        "name" : "Walter",
        "profession" : "cook",
        "level" : 10.0
    },
    "count" : 2.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "plumber",
    "doc" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("59157ace263af55a862b78da"),
        "name" : "Mario",
        "profession" : "plumber",
        "level" : 8.0
    },
    "count" : 2.0
}
```